# Can I use different executor for each @Async method call?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, spring-async

In a spring component, i have this method:

```
@Async("@taskExecutorFactory.getOrCreate(#taskId)")
public void updateTask(String taskId) {
    // update code
}
```

I would like to use a different executor for each call. The executor is provide by the `TaskExecutorFactory` bean according to the `taskId`.
The expression `@taskExecutorFactory.getOrCreate(#taskId)` is not recognized by spring at startup with the error:

```
A component required a bean named '@taskExecutorFactory.getOrCreate(#chainTaskId)'
that could not be found.
```

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: Because it isn't a SpEL expression wrap in `#{...}` although that still isn't a guarantee that it will work. Why would you need a different executor for each call? An executor should have a pool of threads which handle the work, why make it more complex by adding multiple executors.

Comment: I already tried wrapping it in `#{...}` but it did not work. I use separate executors because I need to make sure the update is only done once even if we receive two requests at the same time. For that I am using an executor with a bounded queue of size 1.

Comment: But using different executors makes them execute in parallel and you don't update once. Also a queue size of one doesn't prevent that that, it only puts things into a queue when it isn't worked on (i.e. all threads in a pool are busy). Looks like you are trying to solve something with multi-threading which you should solve differently.

Comment: Maybe there is a better solution for this (I'm interested) but what I'm doing right now seems to work. I have different tasks that I need to update independently. When I receive an update request of a task for the first time, I create a new executor that will handle all future update requests for that same task, and remove it once we're done with that task. If I receive N requests at the same time for one task I need to only process one of them, that's why I use a single thread with a queue of size 1.